# Habilitar JQuery

Tags: jquery

[Codigo exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/Q8KVC/)

O que falta,para reproduzir os codigos destes repositorios em modo localhost?
Adicionei no cabeçalho de script:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"> google.load("jquery","2")</script>
```

Apos primeira resposta: Adicionado

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Continua inoperante

Answer (score 2):

Tente adicionar `$( document ).ready(function() { ... });` em volta do seu código referente ao jquery. Veja funcionando:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.oddNum').css('background-color', '#DEA');
$('#DivTwo').css('background-color', '#FCC');

$('#btnOne').click(function() {
    // Action goes here
    $('.oddNum').css('background-color', '#FFF');
});
$('#btnTwo').click(function() {
    // Action goes here
    $('#DivTwo').css('background-color', '#FFF');
});
});
```

```css
body {
   background-color: #eef; 
   padding: 5px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivOne" class="oddNum">One</div>
<div id="DivTwo" class="evenNum">Two</div>
<div id="DivThree" class="oddNum">Three</div>
<button id="btnOne">Reset odd numbers</button>
<button id="btnTwo">Reset even numbers</button>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Se você está usando um código que faz uso do jQuery, este precisa ser carregado antes de qualquer outro recurso que use-o como dependência.

No [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/), isto parece irrelevante pois basta importar um recurso e pronto, o código no campo de Javascript funciona. Acontece que, por baixo os panos, antes de executar o bloco Javascript, todos os recursos são previamente carregados.

E é dessa mesma forma que seu código deve ser, importando os recursos primeiramente (no caso, o jQuery) para depois fazer uso das suas funções.

De forma bem simples, como exemplo, esse código funcionará:

```html
<!-- Importando a biblioteca -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fazendo uso do jQuery depois de importado -->
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('body').text('Olá!');
  });
</script>
```

Já o código à seguir não funcionará pois jQuery (ou `$`) é indefinido. Inclusive, se executar o *snippet* e abrir o console do navegador, verá um erro de referência como este:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

```html
<!-- Fazendo uso do jQuery antes de importado -->
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('body').text('Olá!');
  });
</script>


<!-- Importando a biblioteca -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Uma forma de fazer o código funcionar é assim:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="DivOne" class="oddNum">One</div>
  <div id="DivTwo" class="evenNum">Two</div>
  <div id="DivThree" class="oddNum">Three</div>
  <button id="btnOne">Reset odd numbers</button>
  <button id="btnTwo">Reset even numbers</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() { // $(function(){}); é o mesmo que $(document).ready(...)
      $('.oddNum').css('background-color', '#DEA');
      $('#DivTwo').css('background-color', '#FCC');

      $('#btnOne').click(function() {
        // Action goes here
        $('.oddNum').css('background-color', '#FFF');
      });
      $('#btnTwo').click(function() {
        // Action goes here
        $('#DivTwo').css('background-color', '#FFF');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Já no caso de tentar importar o jQuery com a JSAPI, creio que o problema seja por você estar importando um arquivo que não existe. Não sei se é possível importar pela função **`load()`**, mas na [página de APIs disponíveis](https://developers.google.com/loader/#available-apis) não consta o jQuery, embora exista um código de exemplo com `google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");` que acredito ser somente para exemplificar.

As [bibliotecas hospedadas](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) possuem um link direto para o arquivo. E não fazem uso da JSAPI. Eu até fiz um teste simples com base no seu código e o retorno exibido no console foi:

> Module 'jquery' not found!

Comment: +1 pela ótima explicação e exemplificaçao.